# Is it possible for one person to like an object multiple times?

Tags: facebook, counter

The number of likes shown by Facebook is determined by the number of likes, comments and shares does this mean one person can increase the like counter by more than one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A person can like something only once, but can also unlike it.  It's like an on/off switch people can flick as many times as they'd like.

Comment: sorry i meant the number of likes which show up on a like button, this includes shares and comments on shares. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/  but can one person contribute towrads this number more than once? by for instance sharing and commenting and liking.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question completely...  The counts are separate.  Adding a comment doesn't increase the like count.  A person can like and share and will increment those separate counts by one each without affecting the comment count.